# sqlplus, export the query in 1 column, and disordered

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I am using a script to do a query in sqlplus, but i have a problem when i trying to export to a file
I have this in my sqlplus:

```
spool hits.csv

SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 100
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP |
arraysize 15
set wrap off

select camp1, camp2, camp3, camp4 from table

spool off
```

But when i read the file is something like (trunc two columns of my query):

```
rows will be truncated

rows will be truncated

20131209|name12
20131209|name12
20131209|name12
20131209|name12
20131209|name12
20131209|name12
```

Then i increase the linesize, but if i increase the linesize, show me something like:

```
20131209|name12
|1                                                                                                                                                     
   |       86
20131209|name12                                                                                                                               
  |5                                                                                                                                                
 |        1
20131209|name12                                                                                                                               
  |2                                                                                                                                                
 |        9
 20131209|name12                                                                                                                               
 |3                                                                                                                                                
 |        5
 20131209|name12                                                                                                                               
 |6                                                                                                                                                
 |        1
```

And i need something like:

```
20131209|name12|1|86
20131209|name12|5|1
20131209|name12|2|9
20131209|name12|3|5
20131209|name12|6|1
```

I read but in all pages say the same headers, and my file is in many lines, and i need my row of the query in only one row of my file.

And when i say show all show me:

```
arraysize 150
autocommit OFF
autoprint OFF
autorecovery OFF
autotrace OFF
blockterminator "." (hex 2e)
btitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement
cmdsep OFF
colsep "|"
compatibility version NATIVE
concat "." (hex 2e)
copycommit 0
COPYTYPECHECK is ON
define "&" (hex 26)
describe DEPTH 1 LINENUM OFF INDENT ON
echo OFF
editfile "afiedt.buf"
embedded OFF
escape OFF
escchar OFF
feedback OFF
flagger OFF
flush ON
heading OFF
headsep "|" (hex 7c)
instance "local"
linesize 1500
lno 0
loboffset 1
logsource ""
long 80
longchunksize 80
markup HTML OFF HEAD "<style type='text/css'> body {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;     color:black; background:White;} p {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:black;     background:White;} table,tr,td {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:Black;     background:#f7f7e7; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;} th {font:bold 10pt     Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#336699; background:#cccc99; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} h1     {font:16pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#336699; background-color:White;     border-bottom:1px solid #cccc99; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; padding:0px 0px 0px         0px;-
} h2 {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#336699; background-    color:White; margin-top:4pt; margin-bottom:0pt;} a {font:9pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;     color:#663300; background:#ffffff; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; vertical-align:top;}    </style><title>SQL*Plus Report</title>" BODY "" TABLE "border='1' width='90%'         align='center' summary='Script output'" SPOOL OFF ENTMAP ON PREFORMAT OFF
newpage NONE
null ""
numformat ""
numwidth 10
pagesize 0
PAUSE is OFF
pno 0
recsep WRAP
recsepchar " " (hex 20)
release 1002000500
repfooter OFF and is NULL
repheader OFF and is NULL
serveroutput OFF
shiftinout INVISIBLE
showmode OFF
spool ON
sqlblanklines OFF
sqlcase MIXED
sqlcode 0
sqlcontinue "> "
sqlnumber ON
sqlpluscompatibility 10.2.0
sqlprefix "#" (hex 23)
sqlprompt "SQL> "
sqlterminator ";" (hex 3b)
suffix "sql"
tab ON
termout OFF
timing OFF
trimout ON
trimspool ON
ttitle OFF and is the first few characters of the next SELECT statement
underline "-" (hex 2d)
USER is "DMSADMIN"
verify OFF
wrap : lines will be truncated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL*Plus is clunky in this regard.  You can do:

```
select camp1 || '|' || camp2 || '|' || camp3 || '|' || camp4 from table;
```

Which will do what you want, but can be unwieldy for large select lists.

Comment: Better use sed/awk/ssam(stream sam) scripts over sqlplus output. Over ANY output actually ).

Answer (score 1):

```
set linesize 30000 -- sufficiently large
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set the arraysize to 100?

```
SET COLSEP |
arraysize 15
```

Comment: and if i say SET ARRAYSIZE 100, the output is the same, not works ='(